Can't render with grease pencil objects, and cannot find them neither
I was trying to rendrer my scenes using Garage Render Farm client, and upon sending to render it notified me that my scene contains grease pencil object which is not supported by GRF (and thus, my scenes cannot be sent to render).
I looked literally everywhere to find that grease pencil object, and couldn't find it. In the data API i found this:

But it is impossible to delete or remove.
How can I delete all grease pencil objects in my scene if I don't know where they are and I cannot find them?...
I would be grateful for help!

If you have made some strokes with the Annotate tool, go to Toolbar > View > Annotations, click -.
Then go to File > Clean Up > Unused Data-Blocks.

Dear KISKAart,
Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this didn't work... There is no annotations present in the list, but if I click dropdown arrow, I see :Annotation.001 which I cannot delete. And so my renderer doesn't allow me to render anyways...

So I found out that you can't delete the grease pencil in Data API display mode, try using Blender file mode instead.
Find Grease Pencil > Annotations.001, right click > delete.
This should remove the annotation from the Data API. @Daniil
